# Touch bar on MacBook Pro asks for touch id to login but no login window

Tags: safari, mojave, touch-id

I just looked down and noticed that my touch bar was is asking for my finger to login:

```
Safari Touch ID to Log In ->
```

I checked all of my open windows and nothing was waiting to autofill.

This is a recurrent problem on multiple machines running both Catalina and Mojave.

Does anyone know what is causing this?

I am paranoid about some unauthorized app/virus/whatever that would be able to capture my fingerprint.

Mojave 10.14.6

Comment: Are there any updates available for any of the OSes, @NLR ?

Comment: @ankii: Yes there are available updates...one of the machines is running Mojave, which is not the latest OS.

Comment: I have this happen relatively often as well. I'm on macOS 11.6 Big Sur.